# what is the difference between After I met vs after meeting?

Tags: word-usage, word-difference

Some contexts to clear things up. I am working with a PhD. student(Ms. S) who she offered me another opportunity in the lab, but she asked me to email her Dr..

And here is the sentence that confused me

After I met with Ms. S, I found your lab's work is my area of interest and I would love to continue to work in the lab

or

After meeting with Ms.s, I found your lab's work is my area of interest and I would love to continue to work in the lab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with either version. In the first, it is quite clear that after "I" did one thing then "I" did another thing. It would work if you replaced "I " with someone's name.

In the second, "After meeting Ms S" is what one might call a potential hanging participle, but the sentence goes on quite reasonably to make clear that the person who was doing the meeting was "I".

If you had said "After meeting Ms S, she..." then hackles might be raised but even that would not be regarded as unacceptable. In fact one hears it all the time from native speakers.

Comment: Thank you so much!  But I am still not sure what to replace "I' with? I am the same person who met with Ms. S and the same person who is applying to the position! I would appropriate your help  If you could clear this more.

Comment: @qure, JeremyC means that "after Dr X met with Ms S" would also be grammatical: he's not suggesting that in your case you would replace "I" with anything. He's distinguishing this from "After meeting with Ms S", where you can't tell until the main clause comes along whether it was "I" or somebody else that met Ms S.